# Custom validations in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a lists of buttons in a form, some of them need to be disabled under certains conditions, here is the code of the button:

```
<button data-ng-repeat="btn in buttons" data-ng-disabled="(btn.submit && message.orderLimit>=message.totalQuantity) || popupForm.$invalid" data-ng-click="close(btn.result)" class="btn" data-ng-class="btn.cssClass">{{ btn.label }}</button>
```

As you can see I have added the condition `&& message.orderLimit>=message.totalQuantity` for my custom validation and for the tipycal ones from Angular like required, maxlength, etc. I use `popus.$invalid` from Angular, I don't really find this way very clean, what about if I need to add 10 custom validations?

Would I have to add all of them in the html?
Is there a way to include my customs validations to use them with `popUpForm.$invalid` or to include customs validations in the input field itself?

Comment: look for custom validation form directives.

Comment: Actually you can use a simple function in your scope which check those conditions.

Comment: Thnks fo your answers